# How to add slider to show multiple view's product in a slider in commerce site of drupal 7?

Tags: views, commerce, javascript

I am working on Commerce Kickstart. In my homepage there are 3 views & each view contain 3 product. Each view's products are shown in a column like below image :

[image]

I want to add slider to show all products by clicking "< >" arrow. How can I implement. Please Help. Thanks

Comment: if you wants to show the product in slider then simply use view slider.

Comment: Actually I have 3 views. Can Views Slider is best to solve my query?

Comment: Do you need 3 slider or 1 slider?

Comment: I need only one slider instead of three rows.

Comment: Yes you can achieve your goal using view slider easily.

Comment: ok i'll try. But I didn't use. May you pls provide me the related link i.e. how to create Views slider. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to solve the issue?

Comment: no not solved. I have already a content type. I can't understand how to apply Views Slider on that content type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17590/discussion-between-smalution-and-samzha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve your requirement using [views_slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module.

Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View.

```
News item slideshow (such as the title, image etc).

The Last X number of X submitted (images, videos, blog entries, forum posts, comments, testimonials, etc.).

Rotate any image, based on any filters you can apply in views.

Hottest new products for any ecommerce drupal site.

Rotate contact links, share links, etc.
```

Implementation :

Steps:

Enable view slideshow module.

Create a view using existing content type(ex-product).

View format: Slideshow

Add item for slideshow (such as the title, image etc).

**For getting Next & Previous link**

Goto view slider settings

Enable the controls as text.

It displays 'next','pause' and 'previous' link

Later you change the css as per requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Smalution.. it's working but I have 1 query that I want to add "<" & ">" arrow for next & previous.

Comment: Have you check the view slider controller settings. Refer this link http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-use-images-next-and-previous-buttons-views-slideshow-or-how-replace-any-textual-link-image

Comment: Thanks @Smalution. I got arrows in place of text. But I have 1 more query. Please check http://tempsend.com/4E910D5326
I got this. Due to 3 view, each view contain arrows. Is this possible to show only 2 arrows "left & right" only to control all view to slide products instead of all those.

Answer (score 1):

if you wants multiple product in slider with next previous arrows then go for [`jcarousel`](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module

Features

```
Built-in Views support.
AJAX-loading of additional items as needed.
Carousel pager/navigation to jump between multiple pages.
Circular wrapping of items.
API for direct usage of jCarousel without Views.
```

Comment: hello may you pls check this one for slider "https://www.drupal.org/node/1985624"